# didReceiveRemoteNotification not getting called in background iOS 14 even with content-available = 1

Tags: swift, background, ios14, remote-notifications

unfortunately I ran out of the questions limit, so I had to edit this previously asked question to get some help from the community. The issue is fetchCompletionHandler has stopped working in background iOS 14, Push notification is received but this function does not call until user's interaction. Am wondering what could go wrong, where as I have already added the header values recommended in iOS 13 and the Push notification payload is as follows but still no success;

```
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
alert =     {
    body = "Hi, you have received a notification;
    title = "You have received a notification";
};
"content-available" = 1;
"mutable-content" = 1;
sound = default;},AnyHashable("extraPayLoad"): {
action = "cl_blocked";
"read_id" = "123";
"short_msg" = "You have received a notification";}]
```

also the plist looks like this;

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Do anyone have idea how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think it will be more secure, if you use webservice instead

Comment: it's not that much secure to interact with the database directly. better to created web services and use the services. because we need to provide all the details of DB in order to connect it. if some 1 reverse engineer your app its causes security problem.